# jQuery loading UI with getScript causing errors with undefined datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

So I am trying to create a widget to go onto third party websites, The widget is using the jquery UI as well but trying to get the datepicker to work is just not working as expected.

Here is my code.

```
(function () {
        // Localize jQuery variable
        var myJquery;
        /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
        if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.2.1') {
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js");
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // Same thing but for IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
            // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
            console.log('need to load latest jQuery')
        } else {
            console.log('dont need to load jQuery')
            myJquery = window.jQuery;
            loadJQueryUi();
        }

        function scriptLoadHandler() {
            console.log('latest jQuery loaded')
            myJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            loadJQueryUi();
        }
        function loadJQueryUi() {
            console.log('main function')
            /******* Load UI *******/
            myJquery.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', function () {
                myJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
                console.log('loaded jquery UI')
                // jQueryApr(document).ready(function ($) {
                    setHandlers(myJquery)
                // });
            });
            /******* Load UI CSS *******/
            var css_link = myJquery("<link>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');
        }

        function setHandlers($) {
            console.log('document ready')

                $('#start-date').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "M dd, yy",
                    minDate: 'D',
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    onSelect: function () {
                        console.log($(this).val())
                    }
                });

        }
    })();
```

Running the above I get datepicker function is not defined. BUT if I wrap the datepicker function in a focus event ie.

```
$(document).on('focus', '#start-date', function(){
    $('#start-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "M dd, yy",
        minDate:'D',
        numberOfMonths:1,
        onSelect:function () {
            console.log($(this).val())
            }
        });
});
```

This works.. Also I have tried wrapping my setHandlers function with a document ready but has made no effect.  Is there an obvious problem to my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery doesn't exist globally yet while inside the scope of your anonymous function. If you want to use a Jquery function, like datepicker, you would need to access that function via your Jquery object, myJquery. It works inside the document.focus code block because Jquery has been globally loaded by the time that code is run. You will likely need to leave your datepicker call inside some event handler like document.focus or document.ready in order for it to work as expected.

Comment: I am passing myJquery through the function setHandlers(myJquery).. Is this not correct?

Comment: You're right, I see that now. However, given the situation you described, the problem I described in my answer still seems to be what is happening. Because it is being passed in, instead of existing globally, it seems that you are not able to chain functions normally, meaning you would still need to execute that code elsewhere, like in your focus event.